# Incomplete rows fetched by Databricks from Event Hubs using PySpark

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-eventhub

I have a query regarding Azure event hubs and Databricks. I have been trying to read data in databricks coming from Azure event hubs, but it is not reading complete rows. For example, I am sending 100 rows of a csv file from event hubs, it is only reading 95,94 or even lesser, depending upon the time I execute the reading code in Databricks. Does anyone have any clue what mistake I am making? What offset parameters (if any) should I use for this?

Please help me out as I'm stuck on this for days now. Thank you!

I have been using the following code:

```
connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://ingestion-layer.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=user-policy;SharedAccessKey=lZXpYf5ZISKuhHwSXRdse0ZWDGcEVsqLxjUojRwb03Y=;EntityPath=data-ingestion"

ehConf = {}
ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = connectionString

# Encrypt ehConf connectionString property
ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString)



from datetime import datetime as dt
import json

# Start from beginning of stream
startOffset = "-1"

# End at the current time. This datetime formatting creates the correct string format from a python datetime object
#endTime = dt.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")


# Create the positions
startingEventPosition = {
  "offset": startOffset,  
  "seqNo": -1,            
  "enqueuedTime": None,   
  "isInclusive": True
}

#endingEventPosition = {
 # "offset": None,          
  #"seqNo": 100,              
  #"enqueuedTime": endTime,
  #"isInclusive": True
#}


# Put the positions into the Event Hub config dictionary
ehConf["eventhubs.startingPosition"] = json.dumps(startingEventPosition)
#ehConf["eventhubs.endingPosition"] = json.dumps(endingEventPosition)
```

## Read events from the Event Hub

```
df = spark.readStream.format("eventhubs").options(**ehConf).load()

# Visualize the Dataframe in realtime

#display(df)

readInStreamBody = df.withColumn("body", df["body"].cast("string"))
display(readInStreamBody)
```

Upon running this code, I am getting the aforementioned rows depending upon when I am starting the Databricks read code.

Please anyone help me out with this!

Comment: please enter the code as text, not images

Comment: I'm new to this platform, can you tell me how to enter code as text?

Comment: use triple backticks to mark paragraphs of the code - see help: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Is it okay now?

Comment: No - you didn't insert your actual code, but instead made links broken...

Comment: Oh. I'm not getting this. I don't have code, but only have text and three images in my question. Since it is saying that images are written in the form of code, so I am just indenting them or using backticks on them. Why are they getting broken? I am also not indenting my text.

Comment: You have code as screenshots showing your notebooks. Just copy the code from the notebooks cells into your question. And only insert result of `display` as an image

Comment: I hope it is okay now...

Comment: Yes! Much better